# gaq is not defined opencart 2.0

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, opencart

I'm trying to track transactions in OpenCart, but I'm getting this message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _gaq is not defined(anonymous function)
```

This is how I'm trying to do the tracking in my

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/success.tpl`


      <!--THIS IS THE START OF THE TRACKING MOD-->
  <?php if($order_tracker){ 
        echo "SUCESSO";
        $tracking_info = '<script type="text/javascript">';

        //ADD TOP LEVEL TRACKING INFO
    $tracking_info .= "_gaq.push(['_addTrans', '" . $order_tracker['order_id'] . "', '" . $order_tracker['store_name'] . "', '" . $order_tracker['total'] . "', '" . $order_tracker['tax'] . "', '" . $order_tracker['shipping'] . "', '" . $order_tracker['city'] . "', '" . $order_tracker['state'] . "', '" . $order_tracker['country'] . "']);";

        //ADD INFO FOR EACH PRODUCT
        foreach($order_tracker['products'] as $product){
          $tracking_info .= "_gaq.push(['_addItem', '" . $product['order_id'] . "', '" . $product['model'] . "', '" . $product['name'] . "', '', '" . $product['price'] . "', '" . $product['quantity'] . "']);";
        }

        //ADD THE CURRENCY OF THE TRANSACTION
        $tracking_info .= "_gaq.push(['_set', 'currencyCode', '" . $order_tracker['currency'] . "']);";

        $tracking_info .= '</script>';

        print $tracking_info;

  } ?>
    <!--THIS IS THE END OF THE TRACKING MOD-->
```

And this is how it's being interpreted in Chrome Console

```
   <!--THIS IS THE START OF THE TRACKING MOD-->
  <script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push(['_addTrans', '17', 'Zelulares', '805.0000', '', '5.0000', 'Sao Paulo', 'São Paulo', 'Brazil']);_gaq.push(['_addItem', '17', 'Product 16', 'MacBook', '', '500.00', '1']);_gaq.push(['_addItem', '17', 'Product 14', 'iMac', '', '100.00', '3']);_gaq.push(['_set', 'currencyCode', 'USD']);</script>    <!--THIS IS THE END OF THE TRACKING MOD-->
```

**EDIT:**

This is the analytics.js code that I included in opencart admin:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: Did you include the [GA base code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#tracking-code-quickstart)? Or are you possibly using [Universal Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/#quickstart) (analytics.js) and your code is still using the old style (ga.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MisterPhillip pointed out your transaction code uses a different (older) version than the code you use to create a tracker and needs to be updated. You need to "require" the E-Commerce-libary (after you have created the tracker but before you add transactions or products) and convert the tracking code to the new version. You are looking for output that looks like this (full example):

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
    ga('require', 'ecommerce');

    ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
      'id': '17',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
      'affiliation': 'Zelulares',   // Affiliation or store name.
      'revenue': '805.0000',               // Grand Total.
      'shipping': '',                  // Shipping.
      'tax': '5.0000'                     // Tax.
    });

    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
      'id': '17',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
      'name': 'MacBook',    // Product name. Required.
      'sku': 'Product 16',                 // SKU/code.
      'price': '500',                 // Unit price.
      'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity.
    });

    ga('ecommerce:send');

    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Note that the geograpical info in the transaction no longer exists in Universal Analytics, you would need to re-create this a custom dimension. Also this is assuming standard E-Commerce-tracking (there is also an "enhanced" version which is a lot more complicated to set up).